# Google maps overlapping marker spiderfier ALWAYS keep spiderfied

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerspiderfier

Overlapping markers are unspiderfied when I click the map even though I have {keepSpiderfied: true}, how can I always keep all markers spiderfied?

Hitbox on my custom markers are also buggy when I have more than 2 markers overlapping, any solution to this would be insanely helpful.

Thx!

Answer (score 2):

The sole purpose of `keepSpiderfied` is to avoid unspiderfying when you [click on a marker](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/master/lib/oms.coffee#L140).

[Clicking on the map](https://github.com/jawj/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/blob/master/lib/oms.coffee#L59) will call `unspiderfy` regardless of that setting, and so does changing zoom or mapType.

So I guess your only choice here is to fork the repo, or just download the library and add it to version control making your own modifications.